# Resta en PHP de números iguales da negativo

Tags: php, double, float

Tengo dos float iguales que al restarlo da el resultado negativo.

Ejemplo: 42.22 - 42.22 = -1.4.....

A alguien le a pasado y sabe solucionarlo?

Comment: Puedes mostrar el código que estás usando ??

Comment: A mi me da todo cero: `echo (42.22 - 42.22);` da `0`. Luego `var_dump(42.22 - 42.22);` dice: `float(0)` y también `print_r(42.22 - 42.22);` me da `0`.

Comment: Recojo dos double  iguales de la base de datos y se muestran bien pero a la hora de hacer la resta me saca un resultado negativo.

Comment: ¿Cómo almacenas los valores y cómo haces la resta? Muestra el código. Es muy probable que los valores no sean los que piensas o que sean modificados en alguna parte. Ya me estoy imaginando un código lleno de `if` o de bloques de código con llaves abiertas y cerradas por todos lados :)

Comment: $result = $num - $nums; echo $result; He comprobado lo que sacaba de la base de datos y no se modifica en ningún lado y seguido hago la resta y la muestro. No hay nada mas.

Comment: No será que el separador de decimales es distinto en uno de los dos?

Comment: @user3139428 agrega el código en tu pregunta de lo contrario sería difícil emular el problema que estas experimentando, lo que comentas da como resultado 0.

Answer (score 1):

Probá parseando a float con `floatval()` antes de ejecutar la resta. Sino hacé un `vardump()` de las dos variables a restar, como para tener un poco más de visión.